# nesting multiple level of array with associative

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
data = [{'name':'John'},
 {'name':'Smith'},
 {'name':'James'}]
```

how to format the above array into this

```
var name = {
    "user": {
        "name" : [{'name':'John'},
                  {'name':'Smith'},
                  {'name':'James'}]
    }
}
```

I tried var name['name'] = data and don't know how to wrap the result. I want to wrap the result with 'user' as it assoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign properties as you create the object. Either first create the object and then set the property:

```
var name = {};
name.user = { name : data };
```

or create the entire object at once:

```
var name = { user: { name: data } };
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize name as object first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{'name':'John'},
 {'name':'Smith'},
 {'name':'James'}]

var name = {
    "user": {
        "name" : data
    }
}
```